# How to write a function to calculate total price, clear button values and submit The form

Tags: javascript, html

Have tried everything but it does not seem to be working, and I am new to javascript, any help would be grateful.
Thank you.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="form">
    <form name="this form" method="post" action="">
      <label> Item description</label>
      <input type="text" name="Item description" value="Red copper bowl" />
      <label>Quantity</label>
      <input type="number" name="quantity" value="1" />
      <label> Price</label>
      <input type="number" name="price" value="$450" readonly="" />
      <label>total price</label>
      <input type="Number" name="" value="" />
      <input type="button" value="Calculate Total" onclick="calculate total()" />
      <input type="button" value="submit" on-submit="submit()" />
    </form>
  </div>

  <script type="text/JavaScript">
    function calculateTotal() { var totalPrice = "$450"; var Quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value; var price = document.getElementById("price").value; total = quantity * price; alert("Quantity cannot be zero, blank or null"); alert("Price cannot be zero, blank or null"); document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = totalPrice; return; } function clearTotal() { document.getElementById("Quantity").innerHTML = ""; document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = ""; return; } function
    submit() { return confirm( "is the information correct ? \n ItemDescription = RedBowl nQuantity = 1 nPrice = $450" ); }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `total = quantity *price;` here `total` is not declared (make it `var total`) and `quantity` is `Quantity` , you can return `total` . please go through simple examples ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Your_first_form

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
function calculateTotal() { 
    var totalPrice = "$450"; 
    
    //case matters as in "total = quantity * price <- quantity is lowercase
    //var Quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value; 
    var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value; 
    
    var price = document.getElementById("price").value; 
    total = quantity * price; 
    alert("Quantity cannot be zero, blank or null"); 
    alert("Price cannot be zero, blank or null"); 

    //do you want the value from "total = quantity * price"? or the "var totalPrice = "$450""?
    document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = totalPrice; <- you probably want "total" not "total price"
    return; 
} 

function clearTotal() 
{ 
    document.getElementById("Quantity").innerHTML = ""; 
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = ""; 
    return; 
} 

function submit() 
{ 
    return confirm( "is the information correct ? \n ItemDescription = RedBowl nQuantity = 1 nPrice = $450" ); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So... there are countless issues with your code, but the most important thing is readability. Please learn to structure your code.

**few mistakes to point out:**

1. There is no method *'on-submit'*
2. Read naming convention of JS functions, as 'calculate total()' is not a valid name, which you are using on calculate total button.
3. You are trying to get elements by IDs but you forgot to assign any.
4. Again naming convention, *'Quantity'* is used to store the value of quantity input box but you used *'quantity'* in the calculation.
5. you can not set innerHtml for input box.
6. you assigned a string value to 'totalPrice' and then using the same in multiplication.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="form">
    <form name="this form" method="post" action="">
      <label> Item description</label>
      <input type="text" name="Item description" value="Red copper bowl" />
      <label>Quantity</label>
      <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" />
      <label> Price</label>
      <input type="number" id="price" name="price" value="450" readonly="" />
      <label>total price</label>
      <input type="number" id="totalPrice" name="" value="450" />
      <input type="button" value="Calculate Total" onclick="calculateTotal()" />
      <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="submit()" />
       <input type="button" value="reset" onclick="clearTotal()" />
    </form>
  </div>

  <script type="text/JavaScript">
    function calculateTotal() { 
      //const totalPrice = "450";
      let quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value; 
      let price = document.getElementById("price").value;
      let total = quantity * price;
      console.log(total)
      document.getElementById("totalPrice").value = total; 
    }
    
    function clearTotal() { 
      document.getElementById("quantity").value = 1;
      document.getElementById("totalPrice").value = 450; 
    } 
    function submit() { 
        return window.confirm( "is the information correct ? \n ItemDescription = RedBowl nQuantity = 1 nPrice = $450" ); 
    }
  </script>
  
</body>

</html>
```

and last but not least: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp